# How to add icon to textview in widget

Tags: android, widget

I used `android:drawableLeft`, but this led to `Problem loading widget`.

```
<TextView
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="7"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/classroom"
                    android:text="01A201" />
```

Problen loading widget
[image: Problen image]

I've tried using a higher level API, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Use drawable file it will works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<TextView

```
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/classroom"
                android:text="01A201" />
```

my suggetion :

you can enter your icon in drwable and than add this line :

android:drwableleft = "@drwable/your icon"